# Error when sending message to AppDynamics through powerhsell using invoke-restmethod

Tags: powershell, appdynamics

I am trying to send a message to App Dynamics using 'Invoke-RestMethod' through powershell which is giving below error

> Invoke-RestMethod : AppDynamics - Error report HTTP Status 400 - Event
> summary is not specifiedtype Status reportmessageEvent  summary is not
> specifieddescriptionThe request sent by the client was syntactically
> incorrect.

I am using below code to send message.

```
 $JSONBody = @{
                   '@context'= 'http://schema.org/extensions'
                    '@type'= 'MessageCard'
                    'title' = 'Incoming Alert Test Message'
                    'text' = 'xyz'
                    'eventtype'='CUSTOM'
                    'customeventtype'='appDcustomevent'

                    }

$json = ConvertTo-Json $JSONBody -Depth 100
$headers = @{Authorization='Basic '+[Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes('username@account:password'))}
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://rest api url/events' -Proxy 'proxy url:80' -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $json -ContentType 'application/json'
```

Please help me understand how to fix this issue as i have no clue.

Thanks in advance,
Usha.

Comment: Do you have a link to the doc for this method ? Usually you'll get a sample of what it should look like and what are the mandatory parameters. Compare your `$json` variable with the sample and make sure everything is there and that it match the format presented in the API doc. Based on your error message ,it looks like you have at least 1 additional properties not present that is mandatory to make that call.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I am following below url reference to send alert message. I am refering to 'Post request with adding json content' section
https://community.appdynamics.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/How-do-I-use-REST-API-calls-in-a-PowerShell-script/ta-p/37193

Answer (score 0):

Your request is missing the "summary" field as per the documentation: https://docs.appdynamics.com/appd/20.x/en/extend-appdynamics/appdynamics-apis/alert-and-respond-api/events-and-action-suppression-api#EventsandActionSuppressionAPI-CreateaCustomEvent

(Every field marked as Mandatory under "Input parameters" table must be included in the request)

**Update:**

Below is tested as working, seems the JSON version does indeed have issues - so switched to using query params and this works as intended.

```
$application_id = "<APPLICATION_NAME>"
$summary = "This_is_a_summary"
$severity = "INFO"
$eventtype = "CUSTOM"
$controller = "<CONTROLLER_URL_NO_PROTOCOL>"
$port = "8090"
$protocol = "http"
$account = "<ACCOUNT>"
$username = "<USERNAME>"
$password = "<PASSWORD>"
$controllerEndpoint = "controller/rest/applications/${application_id}/events"
$restURL = "${protocol}://${controller}:${port}/${controllerEndpoint}?severity=${severity}&summary=${summary}&eventtype=${eventtype}"
"$restURL"
$headers = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("${username}@${account}:${password}"))}
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $restURL -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $JSON -ContentType "application/json"
$response.content
```

Comment: yeah, i did try giving summary field as well but no luck